# Where to put environment variables on the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app on a production server and an `.rb` file where I do this:

```
Rails.configuration.my_sect = if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  {
    secret_key: 'some_secrete',
    public_key: 'some_public'
  }
else
  {
    secret_key: ENV['key1'],
    public_key: ENV['key2']
  }
end
```

The application is on a Linux server. What's the best place to put the values of those `secret_key` and `public_key` on the server so `ENV['key1']` and `ENV['key2']` can always be accessible?

I don't want to use any gem or Capistrano.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Environment variables on production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150736/environment-variables-on-production)

Comment: @mdesantis, it's not.

Comment: How do you run your application? If you use for example `foreman`, it will read `.env` if it's present.

Comment: @Jesper, I don't use foreman.

Comment: This question looks related: [Setting Environment Variables in Rails 3 (Devise + Omniauth)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648620/setting-environment-variables-in-rails-3-devise-omniauth)

Answer (score 1):

I would put them in the server script, because, for example, shell configuration files like `~/.bashrc` are not loaded in cron scripts or other scenarios.

The "server script" could be as simple as `key1=foo key2=baz rails s`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/config/en_vars.rb` to `.gitignore`

Create a file `config/en_vars.rb` and put your variables there:

```
ENV['key1']='foo'
ENV['key2']='bar'
```

Then in `config/environment.rb` add the lines below the `require` line:

```
en_vars = File.join(Rails.root, 'config/en_vars.rb')
load(en_vars) if File.exists?(en_vars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you say you don't want to use any gem, I recommend you to use [`dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv); even if it's not suggested to use it on a production environment.

Otherwise, the simplest *plain* solution is:

1. create a per-project environment variables file (let's say `"$PROJECT_DIR/.env"`)
2. Add it to `.gitignore`
3. execute it before the application server starting, with something like

   ```
   source "$PROJECT_DIR/.env" && rails server
   ```

But that's what `dotenv` is created for, so why reinvent the wheel?