# Rails Zoho Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 530

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, zoho

I'm trying to configure Zoho mail smtp and i don't understand what do i do wrong. In development mode everything is ok but in production i have the error below when i send email:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
```

My production env settings:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'not-real.com' }

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  port: 465,
  ssl: true,
  tls: true,
  authentication: :login,
  address: 'smtp.zoho.eu',
  domain: 'not-real.com',
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  password:  ENV['ZOHO_PASSWORD'],
  user_name: ENV['ZOHO_USER_NAME']
}
```

First at all i thought the problem in wrong password or user_name but not. Next i checked domain in Zoho Control Panel ---> Domains but everything is ok. In Zoho SMTP Server Configuration says:

```
 Outgoing Server Name: smtp.zoho.eu
 Port: 465
 Security Type: SSL 

 Require Authentication: Yes.
```

But could you please tell me what does this mean? -> Require Authentication: Yes.

Should i change something in Zoho settings?

Comment: Solved!. Actually the problem was in setting env variables through .bashrc file in production. So when i was checking the env variables in rails console by Rails.application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings all options were present and correctly but email didn't work. I solved it by using dotenv-rails in my production instead of .bashrc file. Here the link i'm using to setup .env in production https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150736/environment-variables-on-production

Answer (score 0):

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    port: 587,
    ssl: true,
    tls: true,
    authentication: :login,
    address: 'smtp.zoho.com',
    domain: 'mail.zoho.com',
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    password:  'password',
    user_name: 'username'
}
```

That worked for me. Your settings might be fine some local networks block these kinds of packets.

Comment: Now i have this error: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol. This is because of using smtp.zoho.eu. That's why i'm using port: 465

Comment: remove tls and use port: 465 and try it once.I haven't got any errors.It's working fine in my production.

Comment: Actually I have tried many options and it doesn't work. The same with these settings: port: 465, ssl: true, domain: 'mail.zoho.com', authentication: :login, address: 'smtp.zoho.com', enable_starttls_auto: true, password: ENV['ZOHO_PASSWORD'], user_name: ENV['ZOHO_USER_NAME'] Now i have Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 535 Authentication Failed

Comment: If you enabled Zoho Two-factor authentication, turn it off and see.  https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/two-factor-authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

In Your `production.rb` at the end of the file add :

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => 'smtp.zoho.com',  
  :port                 => 587, # change to 465 if using ssl 
  :domain               => 'zoho.com', # if you have no domain  
  :user_name            => 'YourUsername@zoho.com',  
  :password             => 'YourPassword',  
  :authentication       => 'plain',  # change to ssl or tls as required
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :openssl_verify_mode => 'none'
}
```

- Add the same code above to your `setup_mail.rb` file.